# How we can clone any HTML element using drag then drop it in another column (only in that column not outside from it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am doing work on drag and drop in HTML 5. Someone suggested to me to use jquery-ui because they have lot of stuff already implemented.

I am able to drag and drop any HTML element only in one column right now, but I want to be able to clone any HTML element from one column to another column. I want the original element to stay in its origin column as well.

This concept is shown in [this example](http://jsbin.com/aseqid/10/edit).

In this example, "test" div can be cloned and dropped anywhere, but I to be able to drop it only in the "drop" column - it can be dropped anywhere in this column.

After dropping, I also want to resize it, change the position, save the properties such as size, width, height, etc in a file or Database.

Comment: @Warren Sergent : Thanks for that I am new on stackoverflow

Comment: Hi please anyone help me , Anyone who have already working on that . :(

Comment: Which example I linked , In this we can clone only div but I want clone all elements of html like buttons, text box etc.

Comment: There is no one which can help me :(

Comment: Looking over this, there's a lot of little things that jump out. 1) add `revert` option to your draggable. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert Need more info on how you want to resize etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: 2) `var b=parseInt($(this.width));` is not correct. Should be `var b=parseInt($(this).width());`

Comment: @Twisty : Thank you Sir , for reply . After cloning we drag that element into big box . when that element dragged in big box that time , Can we resize that dragged element also resize that big box for make more space .

Comment: see the answer I posted. Read through it. See if your question is answered there.

Comment: @Twisty : Thank you sir , That is working perfect but can I do that for every html element not only div , like buttons, checkbox , dropdowns etc . Can I drag and drop these like this example .

Comment: Largely yes. I suspect some things might cause you issue. Anything that fits the box model should do it.

Comment: You'll have to test more.

Comment: @Thank you Sir , You give such very satisfactory answer . Thank you very much :) . Sir If want learn jquery for dnd . there have any tutorial .

Comment: @Twisty : That working sir , but resizing not working , I want after drop element then I can resize it . Also save there positions and size when submit it.

Comment: @Twisty : Sorry Sir , Resizing is working :)

Comment: @Twisty : I want save it after set their positions and resize . Can we resize #drop div also ?

Comment: @Twisty : Help me Sir , how we can save all changes ,like resize , positions in data base or in file .

Comment: This all depends on element and what you plan to do with it / store it / use it later. All elements have a `position` and `offset` that is based on the number of pixels from the Top and from the Left edges of the browser. Based on your comments, it sounds like you will have a game board or map, and you drag and drop players, walls, and other such items. So you need to `id` each when you put it in map. So there is a lot that can be done.

Comment: I hope you find my answer below to have answered your original question. If it did, please mark it as the answer. Here is something to grow with: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u172wuer/6/

Comment: @Twisty : Thank you sir , You giving your valuable time and sorry for that because I can not explain my issue properly . Your first example is perfect . Actually I am making a crm forum , there admin can make a crm forum , I making it for admin , he can drag any text field , any button , any checkbox on forum and then save it . When that forum is saved any user can access . So that means we can save that forum at server side or data base . That I actually doing sir .

Comment: @Twisty : Are you there sir ?

Comment: Please try to remember that this site is made of people helping each other out. I was sleeping and am at work now. Your CRM may get very complicated. For example, if a new `form` is created and a text field is dragged in, do you want the text field to be appended to the form or not? Also do you want to have complex objects like a Text field with a label. There is a lot that can be done and some good ways to do it. You will want to investigate and research all your needs first and then see how to reach that goal. jQuery UI I suspect is a good way to do it.

Comment: @Twisty : Thanks you Sir for giving your valuable time :)

Comment: @Twisty : Sir , I want know about only one thing , which example you give to in Answer , In this we can drag only div but can we drag buttons, text box etc. and resize as like div (in this example) , Please modify that example for any element . Thanks , after that I not ask more . please help for one time.

Comment: I created that example from your example. Please provide a more complete example and I can update.

Comment: I edited and updated my answer. I would suggest you review it. If it answers your question, I hope you will want to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Twisty : I am not want resize on double click I want when I drag element and drop it that will be resize always . because at double click I am using color change event.

Comment: just move the resize into the drop instead of double-click.

Comment: @Twisty : Thank you sir , you are help me alot I have no words to say , your are wonderful person. But I want learn jquery and jquery-UI I want do more in jquery can you give me any reference or any best tutorial or book .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few fixes to start:

`var b=parseInt($(this.width));`

This fails. I would advise:

`var b = parseInt($(this).width());`

This will return the Width value of `this` and then parse it into an Integer. You may want to consider `parseFloat()` just in case you have an odd sized element that has 30.5 pixel width.

Your draggable had a lot of stuff that was not needed. Changed that to:

```
  $('.test').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  }).click(function() {
    var b = parseInt($(this).width());
    $(this).css('width', b + 5);
  });
```

You needed to add a bit more to your droppable to get what you needed.

```
  $('#drop').droppable({
    accept: ".test",
    drop: function(e, u) {
      var a = u.helper.clone();
      console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
      a.css("z-index", 1000);
      a.appendTo("#drop");
      a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
        containment: "#drop"
      });
    }
  });
```

I moved the CSS to it's own section, this allows you to not have to adjust CSS of each element.

I also added Resize when you double click a `.dropped` element.

Here is everything and a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u172wuer/

**HTML**

```
<div class="test red square"></div>
<div id="drop"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#drop {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dropped {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  }).click(function() {
    var b = parseInt($(this).width());
    $(this).css('width', b + 5);
  });
  $('#drop').droppable({
    accept: ".test",
    drop: function(e, u) {
      var a = u.helper.clone();
      console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
      a.css("z-index", 1000);
      a.appendTo("#drop");
      a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
        containment: "#drop"
      }).dblclick(function() {
        // Enabled Resize on element when double clicked
        $(this).resizable();
      });
    }
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($(".dropped").length) {
      // Disabled Resize on all elements when #drop
      $(".ui-resizable").resizable("destroy");
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that is what you were driving for, but it's not very clear from your post. Feel free to comment.

**Update**

Per your comments, you're looking for something way more advanced. The issue with elements like `<button>` or `<input>` is that by their very nature, you click on them and an event is bound to that element.

To be able to accomplish this, I would suggest you wrap the element with a `<div>` to give you something to move the element around, resize, and more. In the following example, all elements are still active, so they are live when dropped.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5yd6uu45/20/

**HTML**

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="new button-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="button">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <button class="" title="">New Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="new textbox-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="input[type='text']">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <input type="text" class="" title="" placeholder="New Textbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="new label-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="label">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <label class="" title="">New Label</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="drop"></div>

<div id="dialog-settings" title="Edit Settings">
  <p class="validateTips"></p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="idValue">Element ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="idValue" id="idValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="id" />
      <label for="titleValue">Element Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="titleValue" id="titleValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="title" />
      <label for="titleValue">Element Class</label>
      <input type="text" name="classValue" id="classValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="class" />
      <label for="innerText">Text</label>
      <input type="text" name="innerText" id="innerText" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="text" />
      <label for="eventType">Event</label>
      <select id="eventType">
        <option></option>
        <option>onBlur</option>
        <option>onClick</option>
        <option>onChange</option>
        <option>onFocus</option>
      </select>
      <label for="eventValue">Script</label>
      <input type="text" name="eventValue" id="eventValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.elements {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.elements div.element {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  margin: 0;
}

.side-handle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  cursor: grab;
}

.top-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  cursor: grab;
}

.top-settings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top-delete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-wrapper form {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 19px;
  border: 1px dashed #222;
  padding: 1px 3px;
}

#drop {
  width: 500px;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#drop div.element {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

#drop div.element form,
#drop div.element button,
#drop div.element input,
#drop div.element label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dialog-settings {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

#dialog-settings label,
#dialog-settings input {
  display: block;
}

#dialog-settings input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}

#dialog-settings select {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
}

#dialog-settings fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
  padding: .3em;
}

.validateTips {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var tmpElement;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $('#drop').droppable({
    accept: ".new",
    drop: function(e, u) {
      var a = u.helper.clone();
      console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.data("item-type"));
      a.appendTo("#drop");
      makeId(a.find(a.data("item-type")));
      a.removeClass("new");
      a.find(".side-handle").remove();
      var handle, set, rem;
      handle = $("<span>", {
        title: "Double-click to resize",
        class: "top-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal"
      });
      set = $("<span>", {
          title: "Click to Edit settings",
          class: "top-settings ui-icon ui-icon-gear"
        })
        .click(function() {
          var $wrpr = $(this).parent();
          var elType = $wrpr.data("item-type");
          var $tElem = $wrpr.find(elType);
          var inText = $tElem.text().trim();
          var elId = $tElem.attr("id");
          var elTitle = $tElem.attr("title");
          var elClass = $tElem.attr("class");
          var elEvent = false,
            elScript = "";
          switch (true) {
            case $tElem.is("[onblur]"):
              elEvent = "onBlur";
              break;
            case $tElem.is("[onclick]"):
              elEvent = "onClick";
              break;
            case $tElem.is("[onchange]"):
              elEvent = "onChange";
              break;
            case $tElem.is("[onfocus]"):
              elEvent = "onFocus";
              break;
          }
          if (elEvent) {
            elScript = $tElem.attr(elEvent);
          }
          if (elType == "input[type='text']") {
            inText = $(this).parent().find(elType).attr("placeholder");
          }
          tmpElement = $(this).parent().find(elType);
          console.log("INFO: Editing " + tmpElement.prop("outerHTML"));
          $("#dialog-settings #idValue").val(elId);
          $("#dialog-settings #titleValue").val(elTitle);
          $("#dialog-settings #classValue").val(elClass);
          $("#dialog-settings #innerText").val(inText);
          if (elEvent) {
            $("#dialog-settings #eventType").val(elEvent);
            $("#dialog-settings #eventValue").val(elScript)
          }
          $("#dialog-settings").dialog("open");
        });
      rem = $("<span>", {
          title: "Click to Delete element",
          class: "top-delete ui-icon ui-icon-close"
        })
        .click(function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
        });
      a.append(handle, set, rem);
      a.addClass('dropped').draggable({
        containment: "#drop"
      }).dblclick(function() {
        // Enabled Resize on element when double clicked
        var thisEl = $(this).data("item-type");
        $(this).resizable({
          alsoResize: ".dropped " + thisEl
        });
      });
    }
  });

  $("#dialog-settings").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 425,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Update": saveEl,
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      $("#dialog-settings form")[0].reset();
      $("#dialog-settings .text").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    },
    open: function() {
      console.log("INFO: Settings Dialog opened.");
    }
  });

  $("#dialog-settings form").submit(saveEl);

  function saveEl() {
    var target = tmpElement,
      data = {};
    $("#dialog-settings .text").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    $("#dialog-settings .text").each(function(k, v) {
      data[$(v).data("attr-name")] = $(v).val();
    });
    if (data.id == null || data.id == "undefined" || data.id == "") {
      var c = $("#drop " + target.parent().data("item-type")).length;
      data.id = target.parent().data("item-type") + "-" + c;
    }
    if (validId(data.id)) {
      target.attr({
        id: data.id,
        title: data.title,
        class: data.class
      });
      if ($("#eventType").val() != "") {
        target.attr($("#eventType").val(), $("#eventValue").val());
      } else {
        target.attr({
          onBlur: "",
          onClick: "",
          onChange: "",
          onFocus: ""
        });
      }
      if (target.parent().data("item-type") == "input[type='text']") {
        target.attr("placeholder", data.text);
      } else {
        target.text(data.text);
      }
      $("#dialog-settings").dialog("close");
      console.log("INFO: Element " + data.id + " updated.");
    } else {
      $("#idValue").addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips("ID must be unique.");
    }
    return false;
  }

  function validId(str) {
    var valid = true;
    $("#drop div").each(function(k, v) {
      var el = $(v).data("item-type");
      var target = $(v).find(el);
      if (target.find("[id='" + str + "']").length) {
        valid = false;
        console.log("ERROR: Invalid Element ID.");
      }
    });
    return valid;
  }

  function updateTips(t) {
    $(".validateTips").text(t)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".validateTips").removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    })
  }

  function makeId(t, str) {
    var c = $("#drop " + $(t).parent().data("item-type")).length;
    if (str == "undefined" || str == "" || str == null) {
      console.log("INFO: Generating ID.");
      if ($(t).parent().data("item-type").indexOf("input") == 0) {
        $(t).attr("id", "input-" + c);
      } else {
        $(t).attr("id", $(t).parent().data("item-type") + "-" + c);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("INFO: ID was passed.");
      $(t).attr("id", str);
    }
    console.log("INFO: Assigned ID '" + $(t).attr("id") + "' to " + $(t).parent().data("item-type"));
  }

  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($(".dropped").length) {
      // Disabled Resize on all elements when #drop
      $(".ui-resizable").resizable("destroy");
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, there is a significantly larger amount of code. now you could do this in a lot of other ways too. You also have to now enter into how to Save the elements, all their attributes, and their positions. So as this is maybe more than you were looking for, it actually doe snot even really scratch the surface of what you're suggesting that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you . That is perfect , But can we save it as form for future , User can use that form for fill data . Only give suggestion please.

Comment: Yes you can that. It depends on how you are storing it. In a database? In a file?

Comment: There have two methods which I think , One is xml and second is json . Which one is good and fast . there have any example .

Comment: Gear icon setting's form not opened when I click on this , Any idea which I am missing , other all is working

Comment: Everything appears to work properly for me. In regards to JSON vs XML... I can't really speak to that. Whomever is handling the data source would be the one to advise you on that, plus you will need some sort of form handler like PHP that will collect the data and place it in your data source. I would advise you to hire someone that is familiar with Front-end User Interfaces and back-end data storage.

Comment: Hi , Only because of you did , which I want , thanks man . My forum saved now. But there have little little problems like when I resize child div of drop div then that is resizing but on double click that is extended more than expectation .

Comment: Always room for improvement. I set the object inside to have height & width = 100% so that they fill the DIV. The alsoResize changes the size of the object inside too.

Comment: How we can make datepicker input field draggable , Actually input field dragged and dropped of datepicker but calender not show . Any suggestion .

Comment: At this point, I would suggest you male a new question. Include example code etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069921/after-drag-and-drop-datepicker-not-showing-calendar

Comment: Can I send to you my latest code . My radio button is draggable but that is not working in group . and I want update name and id all elements . If you say yes , then will give a link of that code.