# After Drag and Drop datepicker not showing Calendar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am working on DnD html5 with jqueryUI. Everything is working perfectly , only one issue . I use a date picker on input text field. like following :

```
<input type="text"  class="date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;DD-MM-YEAR">
```

jquery :

```
$( ".date" ).datepicker();
```

that is working . But when I drag it (clone) and place it another div then calendar not showing .Please anyone help me .

Comment: Can you provide working sample for the same ? in jsfiddle?

Comment: @patilprashant6792 : that is very large code , I can not post it , I trying post small part of code but it is not working. Please assume that condition which I explained in question , give any idea how that can be work .

Comment: @patilprashant6792 : as per you I did following : $(this).find("input.date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeData('datepicker').datepicker();     that is working , calendar is showing but when select date that is filling there where from I clone it.

Comment: i have updated the code see if it helps you.. I think it is the best way for cloning the datepickers

Comment: Part of the issue is that when you have a Draggable clone, the clone may not have Datepicker tied to it. You also forgot to mention that you're using Draggable with Drop to append the field to a page.

Comment: @Twisty : I know you implemented in which code you give me , when we drag object and drop it on div(droping div) , then that dropped element id and name automatically incremented . please can you do in following js code . There have also datapicker issue which you can see.Last time help . Please sir !!

Comment: @vibog I forked my original and added some for `.datepicker()`, but I am getting unique results so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/djecvLdf/

Comment: @Twisty: how that is working after drop . I am not able to see calendar after drop. One another thing that , Can you mention here how we can update element id or name or value of any html element like your original code I did not get , please.

Comment: @vibog I found a solution and added it as an answer.

Comment: @Twisty : please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091610/how-we-can-can-create-radio-button-dynamically-with-new-value-also-create-mu

Comment: @Twisty : I want learn in depth about jquery and jquery-UI , Can you give some some reference or any best tutorial or any good book friend . Thanks !!

Comment: @Twisty : I add datepicker code as you said but I think my  on drop function not working because of that elements are dragging but not dropping . Please see my code in answers .

Comment: @vibog use http://jqueryui.com/demos/ and http://api.jquery.com/ to9 find out everything you need about both. To get good practice or tutorials, I would advise you start here: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery These courses are interactive and will walk you through a lot of the basic of jQuery.

Comment: @Twisty:Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the following code to clone the datePicker.
HTML

```
 <div id="someDiv">
   <input class="datefield" />
  </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var mydiv = $('#someDiv');
  mydiv.find('input.datefield').datepicker();
  var newDiv = mydiv.clone(false).attr("id", "someDiv2").insertAfter(mydiv);
  newDiv.find('input.datefield')
    .attr("id", "")
    .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
    .removeData('datepicker')
    .unbind()
    .datepicker();

})
```

Please kindly update me if it helps you

Comment: Actually I already implemented drag and drop of cloning object . If I implement your code as its there have have double implementation of DnD . Why we can not change on already implemented code . What is wrong in following statement :  $(this).find("input.date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeData('datepicker')‌​.datepicker();

Comment: i am not saying to implement the code as it is ..... i am saying to use the same implementation just for cloning. Or as a reference. And also the code which you are saying has the same logic as the post. I need you to reffer the above code and mould it as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Jquery full snapshot :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".date" ).datepicker(); //Data Picker
  $('.test').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"

  });
  $('#drop').droppable({
    accept: ".test",
    drop: function(e, u) {
      var a = u.helper.clone();
        count++;

      console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
      a.css("z-index", 1000);
      a.appendTo("#drop");
      a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
        containment: "#drop"

      }).dblclick(function() {
        // Enabled Resize on element when double clicked
          $(this).resizable(); 

          $(this).find("input.date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeData('datepicker').unbind().datepicker();
         $(this).find("textarea").replaceWith(function() {
             return '<span>'+$(this).val()+'</span>';
             $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("name",count);
         });

      });
    }
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($(".dropped").length) {
      // Disabled Resize on all elements when #drop
      $(".ui-resizable").resizable("destroy");
    }
  });
});
    function formsubmit(){
        alert(document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting things happen here that cause problems, but I did find a solution.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/djecvLdf/3/

**HTML Snippet**

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="new button-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="button">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <button class="" title="">New Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="new textbox-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="input[type='text']">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" title="" placeholder="New DatePicker" />
  </div>
  <div class="new label-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="label">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <label class="" title="">New Label</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="drop"></div>
```

**jQuery Snippet 1**

In our `.ready()` function, we look to see if a `datepicker` item has been dropped:

```
  $("#drop").on("drop", function() {
    if ($("#drop input.datepicker").length) {
      $("#drop input.datepicker").datepicker();
    }
  });
```

**jQuery Snippet 2**

Inside of the `drop` function, we would also take this step:

```
  if (a.find("input.datepicker").length) {
    var datepick = $("#" + a.find("input").attr("id"));
    datepick.datepicker();
  }
```

This seems to cover all the bases. Please look at the example and implement this into your own code.

Comment: I placed as like you said but Now My all items not dropping only dragging .

Comment: @vibog sounds like an issue in your `drop` function. Please review your browsers console for Errors. Compare your script to the working example for differences.

Comment: I will be do that . But please can you give me some idea , How I can update name , id , value after drop element , In my js . Thanks !! :)

Comment: @vibog this is already covered in your last question and shown in my working example.  If it still eludes you, I would post another question since it does not relate to your current question. Of course you can also research the issue, there is lots of available info on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

What I did wrong :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.test').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"

  });
        $("#drop").on("drop", function() {
    if ($("#drop input.datepicker").length) {
      $("#drop input.datepicker").datepicker();
    }
  })
  $('#drop').droppable({
    accept: ".test",
    drop: function(e, u) {
      var a = u.helper.clone();
        count++;

      console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.attr("class"));
      a.css("z-index", 1000);
      a.appendTo("#drop");
      a.attr('class', 'dropped').draggable({
        containment: "#drop"

      }).dblclick(function() {
        // Enabled Resize on element when double clicked
          $(this).resizable(); 

          $(this).find("input.date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeData('datepicker').unbind().datepicker();
         $(this).find("textarea").replaceWith(function() {
             return '<span>'+$(this).val()+'</span>';
             $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("name",count);
         });

      });
    }
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($(".dropped").length) {
      // Disabled Resize on all elements when #drop
      $(".ui-resizable").resizable("destroy");
    }
  });
});
    function formsubmit(){
        alert(document.getElementById('dd').innerHTML);
    }
```